# write a batch file to add aworkstation in to adomine and add the DNS and WINS ipaddress to that

Tags: batch-file

I want to write a batch file to add a workstation into domine and assign the DNS ,WINS , and static ip address to that workstation.

Answer (score 1):

In order to join a workstation to the domain, you can use the "netdom" utility included with resource kits and support tools. For example, for Windows XP SP2 & SP3 [download](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=49AE8576-9BB9-4126-9761-BA8011FABF38&displaylang=en)

Then issue the following command.
 NETDOM /Domain:MYDOMAIN /user:adminuser /password:apassword MEMBER
      MYCOMPUTER /JOINDOMAIN

For modifying network settings, use the "netsh" command. Here is an example of setting a static IP:

```
netsh int ip add address name="Local Area Connection" 192.168.1.101 255.255.255.224 gateway=192.168.1.1
```

And for DNS:

```
netsh int ip add dns name="Local Area Connection" 208.67.220.220
netsh int ip add dns name="Local Area Connection" 208.67.222.222 index=2
```

And finally for WINS:

```
netsh int ip set winsservers "Local Area Connection" static 10.0.0.1
```